# How to style individual (or all, each) options/items in Html.ListBoxFor?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

In HTML, when I have a `<select>`, I populate it with `<option>`. Each `<option>` can accept `styles` and `classes`.

With my current project, I'm using Razor Pages with an `Html.ListBoxFor`. I can use this syntax:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.service,
 new MultiSelectList((List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["services"], "Value", "Text"),
 new { style = "display:block; width:600px; overflow-y:auto", id = "ServiceSelect", size = "3" })
```

and stylize my ListBox. However, I can't seem to find a way to stylize each individual option; for example, I would really like to add some padding, as the items are very small.

How do I stylize the options inside an Html.ListBox?

Comment: Short answer - you cannot style `<option>` elements using the `HtmlHelper` methods.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Nuts! This, by the way, was one of the concerns I had in my last question you helped me with :(

Answer (score -1):

One of the best choice and the simplest one is using jQuery Nice Select library. It's simple to set up and easy to use.

Comment: Is this compatible with the HtmlHelper methods brought in by Razor?